# How to use web workers for parallel processing without messing with browser caching?

Tags: javascript, performance, service-worker, web-worker

My web workers (service workers) are running great. Super fast, parallel processing.

The only problem is that inclusion of the service worker means the browser cache for the main index.html page is now almost impossible to clear.

CLARIFICATION: *My problem is not related to caching of the my_worker.js file, my problem is that my index.html now seems to be mysteriously being cached and I can only clear it by breaking the cache on my_worker.js. Is there some way I can just tell the service worker not to cache anything over http?*

I found that I can workaround this by cache-busting the worker. e.g. `var myWorker = new Worker('./my_worker.js?key='+Math.random())`. I also saw other suggestions related to preventing caching of the web-worker javascript on the server-side, etc.

But the web worker is quite large and I don't want to load it over the network every time the page loads.

Is there a way to keep using the web worker to handle my parallel processing tasks but prevent it from messing with the browser cache?

Comment: I assume you mean `Math.random()`. Don't use a random number as key. Instead give your project a version number. For example for version 1.2 load scripts from `./1.2/my_worker.js` so for version 1.2.1 load it from `./1.2.1/my_worker.js` - also don't remove previous versions in case there are still clients using them. You can remove versions more than several days old

Comment: Increase the version number each time you push changes to live

Comment: Please clarify your question: Are you talking about [dedicated (Web) Workers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Worker) or [Service Workers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Service_Worker_API) or both (e.g A dedicated worker's script that would pass through a Service Worker).